# Implicit differentiation question: find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ if $9x^2-y^2=1$

Tags: calculus

I had the question $9x^2 - y^2 = 1$ and my answer was $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = -18x-2y .$$

I was wondering if I tackled this correctly? I am new to this.

Comment: Wait wait its dy/dx = -18x / -2y right?

Comment: I edited the title. I am not sure if you want to compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dx}{dy}$. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: It turns out I waited long enough. The answer in your comment is right.

Comment: If you are finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ then you are correct; it is $\frac{-18x}{-2y}$.

Comment: Some of us would then simplify to $(9x)/y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(9x^2 - y^2\right) = 18x - 2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} 1 = 0.
$$
Then from
$$
18x - 2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = 0,
$$
you can find $dy/dx$.

Comment: (+1), also to get the ball rolling ;)